# Convert timestamp to Wordpress default language

Tags: php, wordpress

I am bumping against a language barrier when I try to push out out meta data.

```
$string_date = implode (';', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dbt_opleverdatum' ) );
$format =  get_option( 'date_format' );
$string_date = date($format, $string_date)
```

Since I save the meta data as a php time stamp, its being put away as a `1451865600` for example (which is january 4th 2016). I pick it up, and put it out via a date stamp which put it down for me as `4 January 2016`

However, the whole site is run in Dutch and as I am looking through the code I notice the functions `get_the_date()` which retrieves the date of posting. But that will output `4 januari 2016` because that goes via the settings in Wordpress it self. It notices the wordpress is in Dutch and takes that in account.

Is there a function I can put my PHP date through that as well, so my date will be propperly shown in Dutch, instead of English?

Comment: what is the value of $format ? You should use %B for localized month name

Comment: in the end, it's returned as `j F Y'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php:

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
>   strftime() functions instead of date().

```
$ts = 1451865600;
$lang = get_option('WPLANG');
setlocale(LC_TIME, $lang);
$format2 = '%e %B %G';
$string_date = strftime($format2, $ts);
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to convert the date_format in the options to the format string of strftime, but if it's your plugin, then you can change it to mean the format for strftime, or if you use it in other places as well, then add another option for this.

Notice: using setlocale changes the locale globally, so it might be necessary to revert the chage after the call to strftime:

```
$current_locale = setlocale(LC_TIME, "0");
setlocale(LC_TIME, $lang);
...
setlocale(LC_TIME, $current_locale);
```

Comment: My apologies for the late responding. I ll accept this as answer, although it never fully answered my question. How does wordpress handle this? Cause if it has a special function on converting this, i'd like to utalize it, cause say somebody buys this theme and is german, the code wouldn't correspondent with the propper language set in the theme options. Now my thought is that it is saved as Unix already in the db, and that it moves through a function, but i cant seem to find the function anywhere in the corresponding files.

Comment: I changed it a bit to use WPLANG. And probably it will also work without that line, 'cause it's already set by WP.

Comment: I defined it in my config file, but it wasn't specified there. I did now, and this option works then. I am not sure why it isn't standard defined to be honest. Maybe it is database call that gets that info. I ll look into the php myadmin for this.

Comment: per update on this,wplang is depricated. : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/broken-wplang-_e-functions-not-selecting-good-language

Comment: My addition to this: `$lang = get_option('WPLANG');` use that to get the language setting of Wordpress.  It's solved now. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Cheers for the update, so everybody can see that is the way to go